# How to Override WL.OptionsMenu.addItem?

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, android-optionsmenu

Working on Worklight project for Android platform. Wondering is there any way to override WL.OptionsMenu.addItem?

This is not to hide settings option menu. From Android SDK 11, option menu will be replaced with action bar. In full screen of WebView there is no way to show action bar. In this mobile app, implemented sliding menu. Each time invoke WL.OptionsMenu.addItem will add a menu item in sliding menu.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Based on your edit:**
Worklight does not yet support the ActionBar in Android, so oddities can happen when using the WL.OptionsMenu API in conjunction with API Level 11 in Android.

---

Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish? What does "overriding" an item mean in your case?
[This is the WL.OptionsMenu API](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_options_menu_and_application_b.html), you can do whatever you want in its limits.

If you mean that you'd like to simply remove the default "Worklight Settings" item, then you need to set `worklightSettings` to 'false' in application-descriptor.xml. After that, you can simply initialize the OptionsMenu and add any items you need to it.

If you mean that you have an existing item you would like to change, since you know the item ID, you can simply re-create the item, which essentially overrides what it was previously doing.

Comment: Worklight does not yet support the ActionBar in Android, so oddities can happen when using the WL.OptionsMenu API in conjunction with API Level 11 in Android.

Comment: Option menu still there. But it is transformed into ActionBar if you want to. Since hybrid app doesn't show ActionBar but need to provide function that previous Option Menus have, so need to override addItem and remove item. Although could do all lookup to add line to invoke each time for addItem or removeItem, it is more quick and formal way to override...

Comment: What you're asking for is not available. If you have a workaround, you can use that. You can also use a lower API Level (or not use a targetSdkVersion, which will then not bring the newer UI to the app...